# Xamarin Forms picker on ios in Release Mode does not show text

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin Forms Applikation with a picker in a page defined like this:

```
            <Picker ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableCultures}"
                    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCulture, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding DisplayName}" />
```

The relevant parts in the viewmodel are:

```
    private CultureInfo selectedCulture = CultureHelper.CurrentCulture;

    public CultureInfo SelectedCulture
    {
        get => selectedCulture;
        set
        {
            if(value == null)
                return;
            if(selectedCulture == value)
                return;
            selectedCulture = value;
            settingsFacade.DefaultCulture = selectedCulture.Name;
            CultureHelper.CurrentCulture = selectedCulture;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<CultureInfo> AvailableCultures { get; }

    private async Task LoadAvailableCulturesAsync()
    {
        await dialogService.ShowLoadingDialogAsync();

        CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures).OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList().ForEach(AvailableCultures.Add);
        SelectedCulture = AvailableCultures.First(x => x.Name == settingsFacade.DefaultCulture);

        await dialogService.HideLoadingDialogAsync();
    }
```

This works without issues on the simulator when I debug. It also works without problems on Android. But when I deploy the application on iOS the texts are empty.

[image]

I can scroll through them and select new ones and the value is changed. I thought it might be a problem with the binding, but it persists when I turn linking off completely.
What can cause that?

Repository Link: https://github.com/MoneyFox/MoneyFox

Comment: Hi, you could have a check with `ItemDisplayBinding` whether has a value when running on iOS device.

Comment: I have tested in my local site and runned on a physical device, there is no problem. You could have a check with network of physical device.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT thanks for your reply. Have you tested locally in Debug or Release configuration?

Comment: I have tested in Debug, it works well.

Comment: I might have not pointed that out clearly enough in my post, but it does work for me as well in debug. The issue only is once I build in Release.

Comment: Sorry, it occurs the same with you in Release mode. I have checked the return data between Debug and Release. `{Binding DisplayName}` seems not own the key when 
in Release mode. Later I will update the answer.

Comment: Hi, I have updated the answer. You could have a look when have time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After testing between **Debug** and **Release** mode , we will see that `DisplayName` not shows in **Release** mode, however `EnglishName` always shows.

The **Debug** mode:

[image]

The **Release** mode:

[image]

**Therefore**, there is a **workaround** to make it works in **Release** mode.

Modify **Xaml** code of `Picker` with binding `EnglishName` for **ItemDisplayBinding**  as follows:

```
<Picker x:Name="MyPicker"
    ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableCultures}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCulture, Mode=TwoWay}"
        ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding EnglishName}" />
```